# AngularJS+Google Sign In implementation?

Tags: angularjs, google-oauth

Scenario:

- I have an AngularJS application (A) on a domain, and an API (B) on another. Any DB interaction is done through this API.
- Users must be authenticated to do anything on A.
- Authentication is provided entirely by Google Sign In - no username and password needed.
- Upon signing in, if the user doesn't exist in the database, he should be automatically registered.
- Token-based authentication is preferred.

What is the best/most common implementation to achieve the above? I've been searching the internet without luck (to my surprise).

Comment: I know what will help you:
https://github.com/enginous/angular-oauth

Comment: Actually I've seen the repo. It doesn't solve the 4th point listed above, or so it seems.